# How to retrieve all document with version n in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

`ElasticSearch` comes with versioning https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning

Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of the versioning here.

I want to find all the documents that are in version 1 so I can update them.

An obvious way is to go through all the document one by one and select those that are in version 1.

**Question:**

Is it possible to retrieve all the Documents that are in version 1 with `ONE` query?

Comment: You can find version for all documents by adding  `version : true` in query.But finding documents from version number seems to be not available.

Comment: Just know that ES doesn't store **all versions** of a given document, only the latest version and which version number it has.

Comment: @Val yeah, I just wanted to use the versioning as a mean to update my data.

Comment: Ok, though, if that's the case you should prefer using a custom `version` field that **only you** manage instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Elasticsearch distributed nature, it needs a way to ensure that changes are applied in the correct order. This is where **_version** comes into play. It's an internal way of making sure than an older version of a document never overwrites a newer version.

You can also use **_version** as a way to make sure that the document you want to delete / update hasn't been modified in the meantime - this is done by specifying the version number in the URL; for example `PUT /website/blog/1?version=5` will succeed only if the current **_version** of the document stored in the index is 5.

You can read more about it here: [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html)

To answer your question,

> Is it possible to retrieve all the Documents that are in version 1 with ONE query?

**No.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripted `_reindex` into an empty temporary index. The target index will then contain just those documents that have `_version=1`.

You can add further query stanzas as well, to limit your raw input (using the reverse index, faster), as well as further painless conditions (per document, flexible), too.

```
# ES5, use "source" i/o "inline" for later ES versions.
http POST :9200/_reindex <<END
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "your-source-index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "some-temp-index",
    "version_type": "external"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "if(ctx._version!=1){ctx.op='delete'}"
  }
}
END
```